# Oracle database role - select from table across schemas without schema identifier

Tags: database, oracle, roles, sql-grant

Which Oracle database role will allow a user to select from a table in another schema without specifying the schema identifier? 
i.e., as user A-  Grant select on A.table to user B;
B can then- "Select * from table" without specifying the 'A'. 
One of our databases allows this, the other returns a 'table or view does not exist' error.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a synonym for this.  Create a synonym named "CoffeeTable" on object "A.CoffeeTable".  You can create a public synonym so everyone sees it like this, or just a synonym under user B.

Answer (score 4):

Just to double check that the schema you are using doesn't have a private synonym for the table (or a view as Leigh suggests) you could the following

```
SELECT * FROM all_objects WHERE object_name = 'mytablename'
```

and look at the owner and object_type information.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe only the current_schema is different. Try:

`alter session set current_schema=A`

Answer (score 2):

If there isn't a synonym, is there a view in schema B that selects from the table in schema A using the same name as the table?  This would appear to be a locally referenced table in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Brett is right. Synonyms are used for this. In fact there are cases where you do not know what will be the schema name in production. Maybe you use A for some schema name and A is already taken in some Oracle instance.

Answer (score 0):

@erno - probably the reason that TOAD didn't show you the public synonym is because it filters the information shown in the list - I don't have toad in front of me but I *think* if you right click on tab you will get to the filtering options (eg "only show objects owned by the schema", "show public objects", "show system objects" etc)